# Gnuplot 3d surface plot with overlayed line?

Tags: 3d, gnuplot, physics

I need to plot a 3d surface (from a file) and then plot a line (from a different file) over that surface. I've found a related thread ([Gnuplot: Plotting a path over a surface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739445/gnuplot-plotting-a-path-over-a-surface)) but the suggested answer was something that I have already tried (and it didn't work).

The surface is a 3D potential energy surface and the line is a trajectory over that surface. The line describes how the system I'm studying evolves over the surface.

I'm currently doing this:

```
splot "trajectory.dat" using 4:6:10 title "{/Helvetica=23 trajectory}"  with lines lt -1
set pm3d
set hidden3d

splot   "surface.dat" using 1:3:7 title "{/Helvetica=23 surface}"
```

but all I get is the surface and no trajectory. The trajectory briefly flashes up when I plot it from the script but then the surface comes over on top of it and that's all I can see. No sign of the trajectory even on rotating and re-orienting the surface.

I've tried reversing the plot order (surface first and then trajectory) but that doesn't work either.

I also tried putting a z-axis offset to the trajectory to check that it was not a case of the surface being plotted on top of the trajectory. This failed too.

Any ideas on how to proceed? I've trawled through the gnuplot help files and there's no example or case that helps. I'm well and truly stuck. Please help! I appreciate any input very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a single `splot` call, like it is also done in the answer to [Gnuplot: Plotting a path over a surface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739445/gnuplot-plotting-a-path-over-a-surface):

```
set pm3d
set hidden3d
splot "trajectory.dat" using 4:6:10 title "trajectory"  with lines lt -1,\
      "surface.dat" using 1:3:7 title "surface"
```

Otherwise, if you are not in `multiplot` mode, the second `splot` creates a completely new graph.

Comment: Thanks Christoph,
After making these changes I can see the trajectory from certain viewing angles but not others.

The trajectory is visible if I rotate the plot such that the trajectory has the white of the axes as the background. However, if the trajectory is in the line of sight with the surface it disappears and only the surface is visible.

Is it possible to have the trajectory visible ON the surface? This is how it should be in the publication.

I can provide a copy of the scripts and images if my explanation is not clear enough.

Comment: Using `pm3d` together with `hidden3d` is not trivial (you can e.g. `set pm3d hidden3d`). Why do you need `hidden3d`? Is it only for the surface itself or should the surface also hide parts of the trajectory. It it is only for the surface, you could try `set pm3d depthorder`. Otherwise it would be interesting to have an exemplary image showing the kind of behaviour you have now.

Comment: Thanks again!
The reason for using hidden3d was to remove the ugly lines on the 3d surface. However, if I change the line type to 0 (small black dots) this problem is fixed. 

After unsetting hidden3d and changing line type to 0 I can see the trajectory clearly from all angles and there are no ugly lines connecting the points in the surface. 

Thanks a lot!! Hope I can return the favour sometime!!

Comment: You can use also `unset surface` to remove the lines of the pm3d surface: `set pm3d; unset surface; splot x**2 + y**2`

Comment: Hmm, `unset surface` removes the lines/dots but also removes the trajectories. The dots obtained from `lt 0` actually look pretty good in the final plot so I'll keep them. Thanks

Comment: Ups, didn't think about the trajectory `:-)`